# How to get the ID of the uploaded file in GridFs to associate with another model

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

I created a GridFS and uploaded an image using this:

```
app.post("/upload", upload.single("photo"), function(req, res) {
res.redirect("/images");
})
```

I have another model for the user:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: String,
password: String,
posts: [
  {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "fs"
  }
 ]
});
```

I want to associate the image in GridFS with the logged in User. I can get the user id. But I want to know how to get the id of the uploaded image. Please be detailed if possible. I'm still a rookie. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The details of the uploaded file/photo are attached to the request object and you can access it using req.file

For example, to get the id of the uploaded image you can do this

```
app.post("/upload", upload.single("photo"), function(req, res) {
    const id = req.file.id;
    res.redirect("/images");
})
```